# Create a square matrix in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to get an number from user an create a square matrix of number*number but I can't do it for now. Could you please help me about it. It should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxtCl.png

Comment: post the code you tried and let us know whats not working with it

Comment: `n = int(input());[list(range(n*i,n*(i+1))) for i in range(n)]`

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
input = 4
matrix = np.array(range(0, input**2 - 1)).reshape((input, input))
```

Comment: this results in an error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 15 into shape (4,4)